# 'react-native-gesture-handler' error when release apk in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I want to release my project and generate .apk file. I flowed react native doc but after use `gradlew assembleRelease`  command in terminal this error occurred.
how to fixed it?

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Note: C:\dev\react workSpace\SafarBeCom\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this, you need to change in the `app/build.gradle` file, in the dependencies part, change:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
}
...
```

to:

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
}
...
```

**AND:**

you need change all of `compile` sentences of your project to implementation.